# Compare multidimensional array with simple array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays I want to compare these two arrays and find the match. If 807 and 200 appears in same keys like 131 then create third array

```
array(131=>(807,200));
```

array1:-

```
Array([0] => 807,[1] => 200)
```

array2 :-

```
$mat= Array([0] => Array([131] => 807),[1] => Array([132] => 807),[2] => Array([125] => 200),[3] => Array([131] => 200))
```

My code:

```
<?php
$filtered = array();
array_walk_recursive($matchingskusarr, function($val, $key) use(&$filtered) {
    if ($key === 131) {
        echo "The key $key has the value $val<br>";
        $filtered[$val] = $key;
    }
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r($filtered);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Mycode  <?php 
$filtered = array();     
array_walk_recursive($matchingskusarr, function($val, $key) use(&$filtered) {
if ($key ===131){    
echo "The  key $key has the value $val<br>";
$filtered[$val] = $key;    
} 
});      
echo "<pre>";
print_r($filtered);            
echo "</pre>"; 
 ?>

Comment: is this `array(131=>(807,200));` your expected result?

Comment: and what if the second array would have only one match for `131` key?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) like this:

```
$filtered = array_column($mat, 131);
//Output: Array ( [0] => 807 [1] => 200 )
```

**Update 1:**

```
$matchingskusarr = Array( 0 => Array(131 => 807), 1 => Array(132 => 807),2 => Array(125 => 200),3 => Array(131 => 200)) ;
$skus = array(0=>807, 1=>200);


function yourMatch($skus, $matchingskusarr) {
    $continue = [];
    foreach ($matchingskusarr as $array) {
        //Get the first key !!!
        foreach ($array as $key => $value);
        //Column already tested just continue
        if(isset($continue[$key])) {
            continue;
        }
        //New column we need to check if it matches our $skus
        $column = array_column($matchingskusarr, $key);
        if($column  == $skus) {
            return [$key => $column ];
        }
        $continue[$key] = true;
    }
    return null;     
}

print_r(yourMatch($skus, $matchingskusarr));
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/Cr2L4

Comment: My first array is skus $skus = array([0]=>807,[1]=>200);
i have another array 
$matchingskusarr= Array([0] => Array([131] => 807),[1] => Array([132] => 807),[2] => Array([125] => 200),[3] => Array([131] => 200));

I want to find that if values in array one matches with values in array two if both values are present in array two with same keys in array two then 
modify array one as array([131]=>(807,200));

Comment: It work like charm but does not work when $sku array is also multidimensional
$skus = array(array(0=>807, 1=>200),array(0 => 807,1 => 200,2 => 415)); 
foreach($skus as $od)  
{ print_r(yourMatch($od, $matchingskusarr)); echo "</pre>"; }

Comment: when i used your function for $skus = array(array(0=>807, 1=>200),array(0 => 807,1 => 200,2 => 415));
it return only Array([131] => Array([0] => 807,[1] => 200))  one array
foreach($skus as $sku)  
{ print_r(yourMatch($sku, $matchingskusarr)); echo "</pre>"; } 
Its not checking match for second element of $skus array

if you can help?